# only display df lines that have more fs usage than 80%

Tags: awk, disk-usage

```
root@SERVER ~$ df
Filesystem  512-blocks  Free    %Used   Iused   %Iused  Mounted on
/dev/YXCV   655360      365632  45% 6322    13% /
/dev/ASDF   3801088     670648  83% 41759   32% /usr
/dev/ASR    1048576     500496  53% 5555    9%  /var
```

How can I pipe the `df` command's output to only display lines that have more usage than 80%?

e.g.: it would only display:

```
/dev/ASDF   3801088     670648  83% 41759   32% /usr
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming you don't have device names containing spaces (which are a pain when it comes to parsing the output of `df`):

```
df -P | awk '0+$5 >= 80 {print}'
```

Adapt the field number if you want to use your implementation's `df` output format rather than the POSIX format.

Without the `0+`, the comparison would be lexical (`9%` would then be greater than `80`). By using the `+` binary arithmetic operator, we force `$5` to be converted to a number (so `9%` becomes `9`) and the comparison to be numerical. Using the `+` *unary* operator (as in `awk '+$5 >= 80'`) works in some `awk` implementations but not in traditional ones (the ones written by A, W and K) where that operator is just ignored.

Comment: `df -P | awk '$5 >= 80 {print}'` works for me: can you include a note about the benefit of using the `substr`? Thank you.

Comment: @jasonwryan: I didn't remember offhand whether awk ignored trailing non-numeric characters when interpreting a string as a number. It does, so indeed there's no need to remove the trailing `%` explicitly.

Comment: `'$5 >= 80 ` works, ie. it ignores the trailing `%`, but `<` `>` `==` don't work in the same manner... whereas the (previous edit) subtring version seem to work for *most* comparison situations, but it too fails when comparing to `< 100` ... I guess that is because it is comparing a sub-*string*..

Comment: @fred: Oh, I see. Numeric conversion does ignore a non-numeric suffix, but the comparison operators work on strings, so here the operator doing a string comparison unless both strings are numeric. The best way is to force the string to a number (with the `+` operator).

Comment: Seven years later... +1.

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, but works. Please replace ext4 with your own fs (or with grep and in case of many). Also replace 10 with your own threshold value .

```
for fs in `cat /proc/mounts | grep ext4 | awk ' { print $2 }' | tr '\n' ' '` ;  do SPC=$( df $fs | awk 'END{ print $(NF-1) }' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' ) ; if [ $SPC -gt 10 ]; then  echo "$fs used more than 10";  fi done
```

Comment: This is useful in case you need to integrate it in a script.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, not trying to steal someone's contribution, but I can't comment yet.

I noticed that the `df` command actually misses anything between 90-99. This change fixed it:

```
df -P | egrep "([80][0-9]|[90][0-9]|100)%"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that since the display order of answers depends on activity and individual user settings, you will have to add a link if you are referring to another answer, in order for readers to understand the context. Also, please note that this would catch `00%` to `09%`, too.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with ddeimeke but this solution only works for 80 to 89% don't show 93% for example.

To do this (for example >70%):

```
df -k | egrep "([70,80,90][0-9]|100)%"
```

Comment: That's not going to work as expected. Did you mean `egrep "([789][0-9]|100)%"`?

Answer (score -2):

```
df | egrep "([89][0-9]|100)%"
```

will do the trick.

Comment: and what happens when i have 92% free on a mount point?

Comment: It works fine for 92%; it works fine for 80 thru 100%... I'm quite puzzled about why someone marked it down.... maybe it is because my `df` output is different.... Aha! I just checked: my default output only shows `Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on` ... so it just depends on what your output is (as mentioned in Gilles answer).. If there is a second `%` column (as in the question), a trailing `.*%` should work: `df | egrep "([89][0-9]|100)%.*%"` ...Now I understand why someone marked down...

Comment: Work fine for all value from 80 to 100: test with: `for free in {1..100}; do echo $free% | grep -E "([89][0-9]|100)%" ; done`. Problems happens if the output of `df` show both space and inode percentage. But assuming that free space percentage come first you can make the command alway good with : `m1` option that limit the capturing outpu. so it becomes: `df | grep -Em1 "([89][0-9]|100)%"`